# What is the use case for the atomic exchange (read-write) operation?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, c++11, atomic

C++0x specifies the `std::atomic` template for thread safe atomic access to variables. This template has, among others, a member function [std::atomic::exchange](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/doc/headers/atomic/atomic/exchange.html) that *atomically stores a new value in "this" and retrieves the existing value of "this".*

Win32 has a similar function: [`InterlockedExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Now, what these operations do is simple: atomic read-modify.

What I do not understand is what the *point* of this operation is. The value read that is returned is "meaningless", because once I can inspect the return value, another thread may already have overwritten it.

So what's the use case for this? *What can the information of which value was there just before I wrote my new value into the variable tell me?*

Note: The `compare_exchange` / `InterlockedCompareExchange` semantics do make sense to me, but not the simple exchange semantics.

Comment: how would you implement lock-less swap without it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your typical spinlock:

```
std::atomic<bool> lock;  // initialize to false

{ // some critical section, trying to get the lock:

  while (lock.exchange(true)) { }  // now we have the lock

  /* do stuff */

  lock = false; // release lock
}
```

See Herb Sutter's [wait-free queue](http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/212201163) for a real-world application.

Comment: nvm that last bit (wasn't thinking :P), but just be careful with Herb's older Dr Dobbs articles, some where found to have serious flaws (found by Herb himself)

Comment: @Necrolis: Indeed, that article itself is a follow-up to a correction of a previous article by someone else that got it wrong. (Then again, some people have even tried to argue that you don't need atomics at all and can just fake a mutex with a standard bool, maybe made volatile :-) .)

Comment: according to intels x86 manuals, you can/could (see Vol 3A Sec 8.1), but using proper atomics is the only way to go :)

Comment: @Necrolis: Well, how would you write the `exchange` in standard-C++? I don't think there's a way to do that correctly in the presence of multiple threads.

Comment: you wouldn't need `exchange`, according to intel, byte reads and writes are atomic on x86, so `volatile bool lock = false; while(!lock); lock = true;`(wrapping the lock in a scoped class would make it safer to use). however, I have a feeling this would break down on multi-core cpu's where the bus requires locking for correct atomicity

Comment: @Necrolis: I'm not convinced. Suppose `lock` is false. You say `while(!lock);` and move past that point. Simultaneously, another thread does the same. Only now do you get to setting `lock` to true. Now two threads have moved into the same critical section at once.

Comment: @Necrolis: what if your thread is pre-empted after exiting the loop, but before the assignment? Another waiting thread can now also exit the loop and have "acquired" the lock.

Comment: Good points, just felt like playing the other side for once. glad I stick to atomic CAS for 'simple' mutexes :)

Comment: That code will sure burn the processor core, just like spinlock with infinite spin count.

Comment: @Necrolis -- you do need atomic exchange; only single x86 instructions are atomic, not read followed by write. But x86 has an xchg instruction to swap register and memory, which is atomic.

Comment: @Gene: It's to be used judiciously, of course. The prime example is the waitfree queue I'm linking, in which you're at best waiting for two or three pointer assignments. Spinning is sometimes preferable over a mutex, because you don't force a context switch.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this lock is not re-entrant, so if your function is recursive it will deadlock.

Comment: Actually, applying some more thought: `unsigned char lock = 0; while(_bittestandset(&lock,0)){_mm_pause();}` that should nievely work, however, I know `BTS` is more than one uop, so its not actually going to be atomic without a LOCK prefix (even though its one instruction doing a read & write).

Comment: @Necrolis - all single instructions on x86 are atomic, there is an implicit lock where necessary.

Comment: Isn't this example incomplete without memory fences? I know that x86 doesn't reorder, still in general case, fences are necessary.